# $ p_k = \prod_{1 \leq j \neq k \leq n} |x_{k} - x_{j}|$ \ Prove that, $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_{k}} \geq 2^{(n - 2)}$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, contest-math

Let $n$ distinct points $i \in \mathbb{N}$ be on the interval $[1, -1]$. Define $p_{k}$ as,

$
p_k = \prod_{1 \leq j \neq k \leq n} |x_{k} - x_{j}|$

Prove that,

$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{p_{k}} \geq 2^{(n - 2)}
$

**My work so far**

$\frac{2}{p_1} \geq 1$

$\sum_{k=1}^{k} \frac{1}{p_{k}} \geq 2^{(k - 2)}$

We want to prove it for $(k + 1)$
$\sum_{k=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{p_{k}} = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{k} \frac{1}{p_{k}}\right) + \frac{1}{p_{k+1}}$

By induction

$\sum_{k=1}^{k} \frac{1}{p_{k}} \geq 2^{(k - 2)}$

$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{k} \frac{1}{p_{k}}\right) + \frac{1}{p_{k+1}} \geq 2^{(k - 2)} + \frac{1}{p_{k+1}}$

**Can someone help?**

Comment: How is $p_1$ defined?

Comment: @UmbertoP. $p_1$ = $\prod_{\substack{j=1 \ j \neq 1}}^{n} |x_1 - x_j|$

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Minimum of $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\prod_{j\ne i} |x_j - x_i|}$ for $x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb [-1, 1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4448464/42969)

Comment: @MartinR Oh thanks alot. Any other ideas?

Comment: What kind of other ideas are you looking for? In https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4450425/42969 I prove that the inequality holds and that it is sharp, with the help of Chebyshev polynomials. That still looks like a natural approach to me. – I don't think that there is a simple induction proof. Note that adding another point $x_{n+1}$ does not simply lead to another $p_{n+1}$ but also modifies $p_1, \ldots, p_n$.

Comment: @MartinR i must better read up on the other trig sol before i can understand this problem,ok i think i understand the other solution that will be talking about the constant coefficient rather than the 2nd coefficient it turned sum of cscs into sum of cots, by shifting by some integer then, it considered the function (x-cot)(x-cot)(...)(x-cot) it noted the function sin(nx)/sin^n(x)  that that function was zero at the same places, and that that was polynomial in cot(x), so it was the same  ok this is a little bit understandable

Comment: here's the thing, we actually have the same exact function at our disposal hmm, not quite
its constant term is a product of cot^2's
we want product of csc^2, or similar maybe just a (1-sin^2)^n = cos^2n
is viable??

Comment: @MartinR can you help me to prove that question with Triangle inequality?